# Why I get the following output "**-858993460**"

Tags: c

Why I get the following output "**-858993460**" when using the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int aNumber(void);

int main()
{   
    printf("%d", aNumber());    
    return 0;   
}

int aNumber(void) {
    int x = 1;
}
```

I am just curious. I know I need to use "**return**" to get the actual **int 1** on my "printf"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)

Answer (score 2):

Because the return value of `aNumber` is undefined. Since you don't return a value, undefined behavior ensues. Don't count on it. On many machines `EAX` stores the return value. If you don't have a value for `EAX`, the previous value for it is used.